# zip command on linux how to force to zip only files and not whole directories structure?

Tags: linux, zip

I want just stupid, simple thing. ZIP all the content of given directory.

What I get as result of:

```
zip -r /home/andi/MEDIA_DUMPS/xyz_media.zip /home/andi/xyz/mega_backend/mega_www/media
```

Is following:

```
➜  home  tree -L 5
.
└── andi
    └── xyz
        └── mega_backend
            └── mega_www
                └── media
                    ├── csv
                    ├── editor
                    └── img
```

while I want just this:

```
➜  media  tree -L 1
.
├── csv
├── editor
└── img
```

MY AD-HOC WAY AROUND USING TAR:

```
tar -cjf /home/andi/MEDIA_DUMPS/xyz_media.tar.gz -C /home/andi/xyz/mega_backend/mega_www/media .
```

based on: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18681595/tar-a-directory-but-dont-store-full-absolute-paths-in-the-archive

Comment: `cd /home/andi/xyz/backend/media` first then run `zip`?

Comment: not a solution.

Comment: I was proposing it as a suggestion not a solution. If it doesn't work for you please explain why.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

#### How do I to zip only files and not the whole directory structure?

Use the `-j` (junk-paths) option.

---

#### zip: Package and compress (archive) files

```
-j
--junk-paths
      Store  just the name of a saved file (junk the path), and do not
      store directory names. By default, zip will store the full  path
      (relative to the current directory).
```

...

> You may want to make a zip archive that  contains  the  files  in 
>   foo, without  recording  the directory name, foo.
>
> You can use the -j option to leave off the paths, as in:
>
> `zip -j foo foo/*`

Source  [zip: Package and compress (archive) files](http://ss64.com/bash/zip.html):

Comment: I got error: `zip error: Nothing to do! (/home/andi/MEDIA_DUMPS/xyz_media.zip)`

Comment: or when using path like `(skipped)/media` with `-jr` instead of just `-j` and `(skipped)/media/*` I got error like: `name in zip file repeated: .gitignore this may be a result of using -j zip error: Invalid command arguments (cannot repeat names in zip file)`

Comment: @andilabs have you got a solution?

Comment: I think only `-j` is not enough. I had to pass `-jr`.

Answer (score 3):

```
Zip command is:
zip -jr /home/jack/Desktop/Backup/20180314/032256.zip /home/jack/Desktop/bopy`
```

That creates a zip file without the whole folder in it. The flag "-jr" or "zip -j -r ....zip /../.."

Comment: (1) Can you explain what you are doing here? (2) Can you explain what your answer has that David’s answer didn’t already cover? (3) Your answer seems to have 1½ sentences. (4) What are you saying about `....zip /../..`?  Please do not respond in comments; [edit] your answer to make it clearer and more complete.

Answer (score 2):

Try

> find /home/andi/xyz/backend/media -type f -print | zip -j name.zip -@

find looks for files & pipes them to zip. -j means junk the path & -@ tells zip to read from the stdin.

Hope this was helpful.

Comment: Just to be complete: `-type f` only selects files and `-print` prints the name (pray you have no weird names. Else work around it with -print0).

Comment: there are subdirectories I want to have in media. Ad-hoc I decided to use tar as demonstrated in updated question.